# how to write DynamoDB table1 to table2 daily?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

how to write DynamoDB table1 to table2?

```
Table1: id,name,mobile,address,createdDate.

Table2: id,name,mobile,address,createdDate.

Condition: only Yesterday added records are write to "table2". And also remove that Yesterday data from "table1".
```

how to do this process on daily basis.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and add details about *WHY* you wish to do this? The appropriate answer might vary based upon your reason. Also, can we assume that when you say *Yesterday*, you are referring to the date in the `createdDate` field? If this is not the case, how can yesterday's data be identified?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own code to do this, but you could implement it as an AWS Lambda function, triggered by an **Amazon CloudWatch Events schedule**.

See: [Tutorial: Schedule Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Alternatively, rather than copying the data once per day, you could create a **DynamoDB Stream that triggers an AWS Lambda function** that can insert the data immediately. If your goal is to have one table per day, you could **populate today's table during the day** and simply switch over to it at the end of the day, without having to copy any data -- because it is already there!

See: [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: i need today data for regular active process. rest of the data no need. but some historical analytics  needs the old days data. then how to move all other dynamodb data export to s3. and how restore that based on particular dated file.

Comment: Are you asking how to move the data to Amazon S3? If so, please start a new Question.

Comment: of course new question, but i need some clarification, lambda trigger start to execute a function that read all Yesterday data and write in table2. yesterday data count like 2 Million+  then how to handle this process.

Comment: It can trigger an AWS Lambda function, but you would be responsible for writing the code in the function. If you are having a problem with the code, please post your code and tell us the error or problem you are experiencing. Also, please note that a Lambda function only runs for a maximum of 5 minutes, so you might not be able to do it as a daily batch. You could use the DynamoDB streams method (mentioned above), or run some code elsewhere (eg on an Amazon EC2 instance).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach:

1) Enable TTL on table 1 and ensure that items are deleted the next day (you can put a next day date into ttl date field on creation).

2) Enable DynamoDB stream on table 1 and ensure it includes old image.

3) use AWS lambda that processes ttl events (check dynamodb ttl documentation to see how ttl event can be identified) and writes old image data into table 2.

This solution should be fault tolerant and scalable, as lambdas will retry on any failed operation. One downside of this solution is that ttl does not guarantee immediate execution. It can in some rare cases take up to 48 hours for item to be deleted, but usually it is much faster.